# .Net SoapClient Connection Was Not Closed

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, soap

I am trying to access a 3rd party asmx service (from my ASP.Net MVC 4 app). Mostly it works fine, then suddenly I start seeing an error:

```
The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.
```

This issue goes away for some time and everything works fine. Then it appears again.

I suspected proxy or network settings but changing those did not help. I am able to 'update service reference' without issues which means I can access the service properly.

Is it possible that this error is generated at the service end and is bubbling to my app?

Can I determine if the issue is at the client end or mine?

Thanks

Details:

```
[System.ServiceModel.FaultException]: {"Server was unable to process request. ---> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."}

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MyTDI.ClientWebServices.TDIWS_SalesManagement.WS_SalesManagementModuleSoap.GetAgentCommissions(String Agency_RegNo, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, Int32 PageNo)
   at MyTDI.ClientWebServices.TDIWS_SalesManagement.WS_SalesManagementModuleSoapClient.GetAgentCommissions(String Agency_RegNo, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, Int32 PageNo) in d:\Projects\TPLTDI\MyTDIPortal\MyTDI.ClientWebServices\Service References\TDIWS_SalesManagement\Reference.cs:line 111
   at MyTDI.ClientWebServices.Sales.SalesManagementWebService.ListAgentCommissions(String agentId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Int32 pageNo) in d:\Projects\TPLTDI\MyTDIPortal\MyTDI.ClientWebServices\Sales\SalesManagementWebService.cs:line 31
```

Code

```
            DataSet ds = null;
        using( WS_SalesManagementModuleSoapClient client = new WS_SalesManagementModuleSoapClient( ) )
        {
            try
            {
                ds = client.GetAgentCommissions( agentId , startDate , endDate , pageNo );
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                logger.Error( ex , "" );
                throw new Exception( "Unable to obtain commissions data from server." );
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error occurs in the database connection. Make sure that the `SqlConnection` object is properly disposed in your server code (`using` statements).

Comment: So you mean I should ask the web service owners to check their code?

Comment: So the issue was at the provider end. They have fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Should I add my comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in the database connection. Make sure that the `SqlConnection` object is properly disposed in your server code (a good practice is to wrap your code with [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements).